# can't create folder after mounting partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions

I tried to mount an ext4 partition by double clicking it.

After that in its properties I found that permissions were only to root.

I tried to create a new folder in it but that option was not allowed  so what I did was starting terminal from /media/username/ and then

```
sudo chmod 777 "partition name"
```

After that permissions now still exclusive to root but I can do whatever I couldn't do before.

My question is, was that operation incorrect? What is the best approach to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean, root is still the *owner*. To make yourself the owner, when logged in as yourself, run:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: /media/$USER/"partition name"
```

`-R` for recursively, so all the contents are yours too

Then fix the permissions because 777 is not a good choice since anyone can write here now; this gives write permission only to the owner:

```
sudo chmod 755 /media/$USER/"partition name"
```

Please note, it's fine to change ownership and permissions on mount points like this, but NOT advisable to do so on devices like `/dev/sda1`

Comment: many thanks to you my friend it worked perfectly!!
thank you

Comment: great, glad you got it sorted @NourAlhadiMahmoud :)

Answer (score 2):

By using the command `chmod` you simply changed permission of the files, not ownership.

To change ownership type in terminal

```
sudo su
chown "Your user name":"Your group name" -R "partition name"
```

Also remember to do this only under `/media/.../your desired file` directory as taking system ownership is dangerous and not at all recommended.

Also `chmod 777` is a dangerous command.

Try something like `chmod 755 -R /media/.../your desired file`

Here `-R` means recursively changing permissions to all child files.

NEVER EVER try this at `/` or even `/media` level as it has potential to break your system.

`chmod 777` is dangerous because

1st digit sets permission for root user
2nd digit sets permission for users in current group
3rd digit sets permission for all other users

4 means read
2 means write
1 means execute

Thus 4 + 2 + 1 = 7 meaning all three permissions

Thus you are effectively allowing any user to alter all your files

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh I didn't see you answer as I was writing on mobile... but 755 is not a good choice for all child files... OP didn't do recursive  777 anyway